# Does the Azure.ResourceManager.Redis package support ACL role management?

Tags: c#, azure, redis, azure-resource-manager, azure-redis-cache

Does the [Azure.ResourceManager.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Redis/) package support ACL role management? Within the Azure portal UI, this a preview feature, so I am not sure if it has been implemented within the SDK package. Can someone else confirm this?

[Azure Portal shows preview for ACL role management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIcE.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft said they do not support this feature as of now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).